# Проверка на отсутствие селектора

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Вот код. Считываем из файла url, открываем его в браузере. Ищем селектор. Если его нет, выводим в лог "не 404", если есть "404". Селектора нет, тест падает, а должен идти дальше. Не могу понять...

```
   from selenium import webdriver

f = open('data.txt')    # прочитал файл
line = f.readlines()
print(line[0])          # выбрал ссылку

er_xpath = '//*[@id="mts-hash-0003a__content"]/div[2]/section[1]/div/h2'  # присвоил xpath фразы 'Такая стр не найдена'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(line[0])              # перешел на выбранную ссылку
driver.find_element_by_xpath(er_xpath)  # ищу xpath
for er_xpath in line[0]:
    if er_xpath != er_xpath:
        print('не 404')
    else:
        print('404')

driver.close()
```

Comment: Что это должно означать - ``er_xpath != er_xpath``? Кстати, в логах должно быть написано почему падает.

Answer (score 0):

@Эникейщик Падает как и ожидается - элемента нет. Все, я нашел ответ

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath)) > 0:
raise Exception("Error element is present")
```

А все вместе

```
    from selenium import webdriver

f = open('data.txt')   
line = f.readlines()
print(line[0])          

er_xpath = '//*[@id="mts-hash-0003a__content"]/div[2]/section[1]/div/h2'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(line[0])              

if len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(er_xpath)) > 0:
    raise Exception("Error element is present")


driver.close()
```